# Validation on Kendo UI for Angular DatePicker not working

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, angular2-forms, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to use form validation on a Kendo UI for Angular DatePicker and it just doesn't seem to work.

I'm doing the following on all other form elements:

```
<div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{ 'has-danger' : email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched) }">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="member.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" required />
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine.

But when I try the same with the Kendo UI for Angular DatePicker I get the following error:

```
<div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{ 'has-danger' : geburtsdatum.invalid && (geburtsdatum.dirty || geburtsdatum.touched) }">
    <kendo-datepicker
      id="geburtsdatum"
      [format]="'dd.MM.yyyy'"
      [(value)]="mitglied.geburtsdatum"
      #geburtsdatum="ngModel"
      required>
    </kendo-datepicker>
</div>
```

Now I get the error:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel".
```

I can't seem to find a way to validate Kendo UI for Angular form elements in a simple way.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `[(ngModel)]` for the `kendo-datepicker` instead of `[(value)]`? 'Cause that's how we are using it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`exportAs`](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#description) defines the name under, which the component/directive will be exported. In this case, you would like to export `ngModel`, which is not present in the component declaration. The solution is simple - just use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]` binding. Thus Angular will be able to select NgModel instance and export it:

```
<kendo-datepicker
  id="geburtsdatum"
  [format]="'dd.MM.yyyy'"
  [(ngModel)]="mitglied.geburtsdatum"
  #geburtsdatum="ngModel"
  required>
</kendo-datepicker>
```

Check the Angular Form documentation for more details, how to show/hide validation errors properly.

https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages

[TL;DR]

The DatePicker component implements the [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface, which makes it a fully compatible Angular form component. The Angular [Validation on the other hand works](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/54e02449549448ebab6f255f2da0b4396665c6f0/packages/forms/src/validators.ts) against [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) instances (basically NgModel or FormControl directives).

With this in mind, in order to get validation working, you will need to decorate the component either with [ngModel] or [formControl|formControlName]:

```
<kendo-datepicker
       name="birthDate"
       [(ngModel)]="user.birthDate"
       [min]="min"
       [max]="max"
></kendo-datepicker>
```

Here is a working demo that demonstrates this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/seJ4jLg9WziemQtCVuxk?p=preview

For further readings, refer to the Angular Form documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/user-input